# How to display data from custom fields I created?

Tags: custom-field, metabox

I created an options page to ad gigs as custom posts in my theme. 
This is in my functions.php

```
    $config = array(
    'id' => 'gigs-info',
    'title' => 'Gig Info',
    'pages' => array('gig'),
    'context' => 'normal', 
    'priority' => 'high', 
    'fields' => array(), 
    'local_images' => false,
    'use_with_theme' => false //change path if used with theme set to true, false for a plugin or anything else for a custom path(default false).
);
$my_meta = new AT_Meta_Box($config);

//Add fields to your meta box
$my_meta->addText($prefix.'where',array('name'=> 'Where is the Gig '));
$my_meta->addDate($prefix.'when',array('name'=> 'When is the Gig '));
$my_meta->addTime($prefix.'start_time',array('name'=> 'When Does it Start '));
$my_meta->addTime($prefix.'end_time',array('name'=> 'When Does it End '));
$my_meta->addText($prefix.'with_who',array('name'=> 'With Who is the Gig '));
$my_meta->addTextarea($prefix.'words',array('name'=> 'A few words on the gig '));
$my_meta->Finish();
}
```

How do I display the content of these various fields in my index.php?

I currently have this...

```
       <?php
$args2 = array
    (
        'post_type' => 'gig',
        'numberposts' => -1
    );
    $prefix = "_gig";
    $gigs = get_post($args2);
 foreach ($gigs as $gig)
 {
echo get_post_meta($gig->ID, $prefix.'where', true);
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to look into using get_post_meta and then display it with that. Here it is on the Codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta

You can look at this example:

```
<?php
echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $prefix.'where', true);
?>
```

That should get you what you need if I understand the question correctly.

Comment: hmmm it's not returning anything

Comment: Before you do the echo for the get_post_meta just echo out something like echo 'the gig id is '.$gig->ID; to make sure that it is getting an id to use and also check your wp_postmeta table to make sure you have values in the table